# Entity Framework Object property can't be set to display in a label

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a question about Entity Framework.

I have a WPF app with a database and a person table.

I want to display the properties of the person object.

One of the properties (code property) can't be set to display in a label.

The only option visual studio shows is None...

All of the other properties can be set to display in a label/textbox.

[Visual Studio data sources tab + property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmcoU.png).

I used the following sql query:

```
USE MASTER
DROP DATABASE PasswordProgramDataBase
GO
CREATE DATABASE PasswordProgramDataBase
GO
USE PasswordProgramDataBase

CREATE TABLE [Persons]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] DATE NOT NULL,
    [Role] NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    [HoursWorked] INT NULL,
    [Salary] DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    [Code] NVARCHAR(6) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [LockedOut] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
)
GO

INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Role, HoursWorked, Salary, Code, LockedOut) VALUES 
('John' , 'Smith', CONVERT(date, '10/02/1993', 105), 'Management', 16, 10000, '014321', 0),
('Jane' , 'Crawford', CONVERT(date, '1/3/1990', 105), 'Secretariat', 32, 8000, '023456', 0),
('Josh' , 'Henderson', CONVERT(date, '31/1/1991', 105), 'Cleaning', 40, 4500, '033210', 0),
('Dave' , 'Webb', CONVERT(date, '21/10/1999', 105), 'Cafetaria', 8, 5000, '042105', 0)
GO
```

Why can't I display the code in a label?

Gratefully, Rob de Graaff.

Comment: How did you create the data source?

Comment: I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model using the solution explorer.
Next I followed the instructions of the Entity Data Model Wizard.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt715492.aspx